# Validate element in xsd which belongs to another namespace

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm using this xsd schema to validate archimate xmls:

http://www.opengroup.org/xsd/archimate/3.0/archimate3_Model.xsd

I have this xsd schema, which contains 2 new elements, but the base xsd is the first one

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema
    xmlns="....."
    targetNamespace="....."
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:archimate="http://www.opengroup.org/xsd/archimate/3.0/"
    version ="1.0">
                
<xs:complexType name="ShapeLine">       
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="archimate:Line" >
            <xs:attribute name="category" type="xs:string" use="required">                  
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>
                    </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:attribute> 
            <xs:attribute name="source" type="xs:IDREF" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="target" type="xs:IDREF" use="required" />
        </xs:extension>             
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>  
    
<xs:complexType name="Shape">
    .....
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

and this is the xml that I need to validate with this second schema.
I have 2 cases. One when I need to validate archimate xml-s, and those I validate with the xsd provided in the link, and in the second case I have xml-s which can contain all the elements from archimate and these 2 types (Sahpe, ShapeLine). This is working fine, just I need that type to be validated only when I want to validate xml-s which contain the new types. So somehow I need the type only in this xsd that contain also the new types (Shape, ShapeLine)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<model
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" identifier="id-5f3cf414a7067b6ee47a783e" 
  xmlns="http://www.opengroup.org/xsd/archimate/3.0/">
 <name xml:lang="EN"> </name>
 <type xml:lang="EN"> </type>
   <views>
   <diagrams>
    <view identifier="id-b3cfd2c8-3ead-4980-985b-0e6078e8a67c">
      <name xml:lang="EN">View 8/19/2020 9:42:44 AM (UTC)</name>
      <node xsi:type="q1:Shape" identifier="id-41bed501-edbe-4526-a765- 
    0f70e0db6ded" x="10" y="30" w="1" h="1" nameinternal="BD_shapes_av_Box" shapeId="5bb51746ec9d2668081e05b7" angle="0" isgroup="False" alignment="" textalign="0" size="72 72">
        <label xml:lang="EN" />
        <style>
          <fillColor r="209" g="210" b="212" />
          <font name="Lato" size="13">
            <color r="0" g="0" b="0" />
          </font>
        </style>
      </node>
    </view>
  </diagrams>
</model>
```

I would like to validate also the type element from the xml, which is below the name.
I've tried to validate like this:

```
<xsd:element name="type" type="xs:string"/>
```

The element 'model' in namespace 'http://www.opengroup.org/xsd/archimate/3.0/' has invalid child element 'type'. Any help is appreciated

This is a part of the schema:

```
 public partial class ModelType : NamedReferenceableType
{

    private List<propertyType> propertiesField;

    private List<ElementType> elementsField;

    private List<RelationshipType> relationshipsField;

    private List<OrganizationType> organizationsField;

    private List<PropertyDefinitionType> propertyDefinitionsField;

    //[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute]
    //public MetadataType metadata { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("property", IsNullable = false)]
    public List<propertyType> properties
    {
        get
        {
            return this.propertiesField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.propertiesField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("element", IsNullable = false)]
    public List<ElementType> elements
    {
        get
        {
            return this.elementsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.elementsField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("relationship", IsNullable = false)]
    public List<RelationshipType> relationships
    {
        get
        {
            return this.relationshipsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.relationshipsField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("item", typeof(OrganizationType), IsNullable = false)]
    public List<OrganizationType> organizations
    {
        get
        {
            return this.organizationsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.organizationsField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("propertyDefinition", IsNullable = false)]
    public List<PropertyDefinitionType> propertyDefinitions
    {
        get
        {
            return this.propertyDefinitionsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.propertyDefinitionsField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute]
    public ViewsType views { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string version { get; set; }
}
 public abstract partial class ReferenceableType
{

    private List<LangStringType> nameField;

    private List<PreservedLangStringType> documentationField;

    private List<System.Xml.XmlElement> anyField;

    private List<System.Xml.XmlAttribute> anyAttrField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType = "ID")]
    public string identifier { get; set; }

    
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "token")]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("name")]
    public List<LangStringType> name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("documentation")]
    public List<PreservedLangStringType> documentation
    {
        get
        {
            return this.documentationField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.documentationField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute]
    public List<System.Xml.XmlElement> Any
    {
        get
        {
            return this.anyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.anyField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyAttributeAttribute()]
    public List<System.Xml.XmlAttribute> AnyAttr
    {
        get
        {
            return this.anyAttrField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.anyAttrField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I declared the type that I want in the ReferenceableType. The name which appears in the xml, is also declared there.

Comment: Did you include the new definition (for type) as a child of the existing model element?

Comment: You need to edit your question and correct a few things. First, get the formatting/indentation correct on both the XML and the XSD. If we can't read it easily then we are less likely to be helpful. Second, your XML is not well-formed - you are missing some closing tags. Third, you need to supply the actual XSD that you are using. If it's too large, remove unused parts. If that's too much work then at least supply the declaration of the 'model' element and its complex type.

Comment: @kimbert - I've edited the question, now contains I think the needed info.Thanks

Comment: Nope - you still have not supplied the element declaration for 'model'. The XML processor will look at the root tag of your XML document ('model') and will look for a corresponding element declaration in the schema. If we cannot see that element declaration, we have literally no idea what the schema is.

Comment: @kimbert I updated now, it contains a schema where the type is declared